# Hide ActivityIndicator and display Title in NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, activity-indicator

i display an activityindicator like

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0);
loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[loading startAnimating];
[loading sizeToFit];
loading.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

self.navigationItem.titleView = loading;
```

in my navigationbar on the top. And i call:

```
[loading stopAnimating];
```

to stop.

This works like it should, but after hiding the activity indicator i want to display a text  (self.title = @"text";) and this is not working.

What do i miss?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you give us some more code? where you stop your loader and setting the title?

Comment: what does not work? The hiding of the Activity indicator or setting the title ? Or Both ?

Comment: Hey, setting the title is not working.

@choise, i stop the loader after calling a http request, and right after this i want to set the title?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `self.navigationItem.titleView` to nil and then set the title.